# How to Customize SubView as PopuPView in Ipad?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uipopovercontroller, subview

[image]

I am working on Ipad application.in this application i use Subview over UISlider as above my Screen Shot show,with the value changed my Subview also get movement.my UISilder is nearly whole screen. i want to customize this Subview as Popupview.as my below  Screen shot show.

[image]

I know how to use Popupview for another Class Xib,but for subview how to use it?
Can any one guide me that Whether its possible to Customize Subview As PopupView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we did a custom popup view for the iPhone and the iPad in some of our application
What we did is to like following

- You will need an arrow image, this image will be a png small arrow that you will place according to the popup location
- you will need a background image with corner borders, or you can use a normal image with no corner borders and use `view.layer.cornerRadius = Value` (we normally set `Value` = 8-12)
- you then will need to do some calculation to find the exact location of the arrow image, and then organize your main popup view to be close to the arrow, this will give you the trick that the arrow is actually a part of the image ( you will have to have the same color for the arrow and the image)

I know these are general notes, but they will get you going 
You will not need to do alot of modification to the view you currently have

Comment: Thanx for quick response.but i have a nearly Full Screen UISilder ,so i want that when i move the UISilder at the end of view.My arrow and Subview also change the position according to location.can u please provide my any link or sample cod to fix this..?

Comment: mmm, i dont have links that solve this issue, you will need to implement the logic by your self, although it will not be very hard, most likely it will be a custom solution you will have to do, depending on the location of your current popview

Answer (score 0):

**try this one hope will help you..**

Make your view to which you want to make popover view …
Lte say your view is… MyPopOverView  .

MyPopOverView  myPopOver = [[MyPopOverView alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyPopOverView" bundle:nil];
UIPopoverController popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:myPopOver];

**[popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:(your slider rect) inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny 
                      animated:YES];**